# What are the columns representing in the top answerers/askers' page?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

1. What are the columns representing in the top answerers/askers' page as in the picture below? I can tell that the light gray numbers are the scores, but what are the numbers in dark gray next to them? I found no explanation.
2. I think there should be an explanation somewhere to tell what these numbers are.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

> 1.. what are the numbers in dark gray next to them?

- Number of answers provided.

> 2.. I think there should be an explanation somewhere to tell what these numbers are

- Just hover on it.

> [image]

Comment: I have been using this site for three years, and it had never came to my attention that it shows that when you hover on it. I think it is a UX design flaw. It should show that all the time, or at least, it should appear without time lag.

Comment: @sawa Hover over everything when in doubt.

Comment: That is an afterthought. Now, I can do that, but I don't think new people will necessarily have an idea to hover over a number. Hovering over a number is not a commonly established interface.

Comment: @sawa - Whenever you hover on such numbers (without intention) it shows us a ToolTip within a second (milliseconds I say). So I don't think new people need to know about it.

Comment: You may accidentally hover over a number (and pause for the required amount of time), but that didn't happen to me in the past three years.